# How to connect to a node from other computer?

Tags: polkadot-js, network

I am running a local node on a computer. How can I connect and get information on this node from another computer using Polkadot Js API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the IP address and the Port to connect, for e.g. `ws://192.168.1.2:9944`.

If you're trying to connect from PolkadotJs Apps, you should run a self-hosted PolkadotJs Apps without HTTPS configured, so that you can connect to an unsecured RPC endpoint.